# What is the name of this?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am using a laptop of HP. Configuration cpu: Intel Duel Core 2.20GHz, Ram DDR3 4GB, Operating system Windows 8. I am using  a external Monitor of Dell S2216H 21.5 Inch IPS Monitor,Screen type: IPS LED, Screen resolution: 1920x1080Pixel, Response time: 6 ms, Refresh rate: 60Hz. I have connected the monitor by HDMI cable with my laptop. My problem is when i am re-sizing the  Google Choromo window fast then the thing is happening shown in the image in the external monitor. My monitor mode is "Second Screen Only".

I have tow question:

1. Why this problem is happening? Is it normal or my laptop display problem or external monitor problem. The dell monitor is new, it has three years warranty.
2. What is the name of the problem?

[image]

Comment: I'd expect this to be a fault of your graphics card rather than your monitor, especially if you're able to provide a screenshot. Have you got the latest driver for your graphics card?

Comment: I have updated my all drivers by a auto driver installation software @ Jonno

Comment: Install the latest video driver from your HP support page and stop using that driver update utility...http://support.hp.com/us-en